# Is there any way to re-assign a const in Chrome DevTools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, constants

I understand that a `const` value is not meant to be reassigned, however consider DevTools is meant to tweak around values while debugging, I think there should be a quick way to try out values. Let say in `app.js`:

`const foo = 5;`

In the console, I tried re-assigning it in the console `foo = 6;`

Obviously it does not work (Assignment to constant variable). I have also tried `delete(window.foo)` but the value still persist even though the `delete` function returns true.

Currently the workaround is using Local Overrides (and have to setup persistent file system) since live-editing won't work (the value is already there and without Local Overrides, the edited value does not survive a reload).

Is there any easier way to quickly change a `const` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

const redeclaration in the console was added in [Chrome 92](https://developer.chrome.com/en/blog/new-in-devtools-92/#const-redeclaration) :)

Careful though - this is only supported across **separate** REPL scripts.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The solution on [Google Chrome DevTools group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-chrome-developer-tools/yxQxiqS8b0w/1mwTSCZVAgAJ):

> You can actually do that, just not using the console.
>   If you have a breakpoint before the code that uses the value that you want to change, let it hit and then double click on the value of the variable under the Scope drawer and edit it.
>   [image]

Comment: Good workaround :) unfortunately if the variable is an object we can't edit properties

Comment: If it's an object variable, shouldn't you be able to just assign them? Like `const a = {foo: "bar"}; a.foo2 = "bar2"`.